# Fixed-length compression algorithm?

Tags: compression

I'm trying to find a compression algorithm which I can use to encode a blob using only 16 fixed-length symbols (0b0000 - 0b1111).

Without any compression, I could use those 16 symbols to encode their respective bit-values (e.g. symbol 5 (0b0101) encodes bits 0101, so if my blob is 100 bits-long I would need 25 symbols to represent it - but doing so provides no compression.

I think what I need is somewhat a reverse-Huffman (in the sense that the code is fixed-length, but it represents variable-length output).

Any ideas?
I only need to do this to one specific blob that's about 2 KBs, so it doesn't need to be super-efficient.

Comment: What is the nature of the redundancy in the data - repeat strings, some symbols more common than others, both, neither?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, use any standard compressor to compress your data, and then simply encode each byte of the result as two of your symbols.

Comment: That's clever, but the output of the decoded data would be compressed and would need to be then decompressed.

Comment: What I need is basically LZ with limited dictionary (16 codes) that minimizes the input required to decode the data

Comment: So? No matter what scheme you devise, you will need to decode your encoding. Compression and decompression code is readily available, and will be much more effective than some simplified LZ encoding.

Comment: Normally I'd agree, but in my case I'm playing with an esolang, so I need something simple to decode